# GROUP_CONCAT distinct dates and corresponding values (to plot a chart)

Tags: mysql

I want to plot a series of unique dates and a corresponding value for each date onto a chart. However, a single date can have multiple values, but I’d like the chart to show only one value per date.

For example:

```
Jan 01: 2342
Jan 03: 2560
Jan 03: 2782
Jan 04: 2893
Jan 05: 3102
```

I’d like to omit one of the `Jan 03` dates and values and just show one value for this date.

Using GROUP BY won't work for this, I need the output to be two lists of values using GROUP_CONCAT

I’m using group_concat with distinct to select only distinct dates, but I can’t get this to map over to the values and only select the values that correspond with that date.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT date_format(date,'%e %b') order by date asc) as dates, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(balance) as balances
```

Comment: I'm not sure that MySQL is the best thing for plotting charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the date to the non-aggredated fields and create a `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT date_format(date,'%e %b'), GROUP_CONCAT(balance) as balances
FROM ...
GROUP BY date_format(date,'%e %b')
ORDER BY date asc
```

Actually if your values are numeric you might want `AVG` instead :

```
SELECT date_format(date,'%e %b'), AVG(balance) as balances
FROM ...
GROUP BY date_format(date,'%e %b')
ORDER BY date asc
```